# nginx image not loading

Tags: docker, centos, centos7

I installed docker and pulled the latest image of nginx and also ran the command docker run -d -P nginx.  next I assigned nginx a port number with docker ps command and when I went to run the image in chrome using the ip address and port number did load get check firewall settings please help?.

Comment: Share the full command. `-P` is not for mapping port, but the small `p` is. `docker run -dp80:80 nginx` is correct. Do you run this way?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
docker run --name localNginx -p 45678:80 nginx
```

and access http://localhost:45678 in your browser

you can replace 45678 with the port you want but not 80, because nginx is listening to 80 port by default.